# Datastax agent.log displays AWS S3 credentials after enabling OpsCenter backup

Tags: amazon-s3, datastax, datastax-enterprise, opscenter

Using AWS S3 for backup through Datastax Opscenter. All the agent.logs displays the AWS S3 credentials like bucket name, AWS Secret key, access_key as below.
[image: agent.log with S3 credentials]

Is there any way we could hide this INFO apart from restricting the logging level?

```
Versions:
DSE 4.8.5
OpsCenter 5.2.4
```

Answer (score 2):

In OpsCenter 5.2.4 there isn't a way to restrict that other than restricting the log level.   The bug is being tracked as OPSC-8839 and the fix will be in a future release.